# Can HoverTool interpolate a point on a straight line?

Tags: bokeh

When I plot a line (with equation y = x) using the two points (0,0) and (10,10) and use the `line_policy = interp`, I would expect the HoverTool to report that y = x. However, this does not seem to be the case (in the screenshot below, x = 6.443 and y = 6.551). How can I get the interpolation to work correctly (x = y)?

[image: bokehplot]

```py
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

graph = figure(width=300, height=300, toolbar_location="right")

data = {"xs": [[0,10]], "ys": [[0,10]]}

ml = graph.multi_line(xs="xs", ys="ys", source=ColumnDataSource(data))

hover_tool_ml = HoverTool(
    line_policy="interp",
    renderers=[ml],
    tooltips=[
        ("y", "$y"),
        ("x", "$x"),
    ]
)
graph.add_tools(hover_tool_ml)
show(graph)
```